# Multiple instances of a component with redux

Tags: redux

Assuming I want to reuse a component with redux, what are my options?

In more detail:
Let's assume I have a generic list component with items and filter input. I want to use this component in 2 places. The component needs to be closed API, meaning it should dispatch and reduce the actions all within itself. It needs to handle state changes and show the filtered items as well. 
Let's assume the reducers are exposed publicly to build the store.
What would be the best approach of building the state object, the reducer and the action.
The main issue is how to 'bind' each component to a different items property on the store state.

---

Update:
Here is a discussion very similar to my qiestion: 
[Using Redux in reusable React component](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1098). I commented on the discussion with a proposal I found. If it will be accepted I will post it here. Meanwhile you can answer my question with your proposals.

Comment: In case if someone is still looking here - another SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906358/having-multiple-instance-of-same-reusable-redux-react-components-on-the-same-pag

Answer (score -2):

I'm new to Redux, and haven't tried the library yet, but [MrEfrem/redux-fly](https://github.com/MrEfrem/redux-fly) seems to me as a very interesting answer to this problem.